# EasyHLA HLA Upgrade Tool Website does not work

Tags: mhc

I'm trying to use Easy HLA, HLA Upgrade (https://hla.univ-nantes.fr/recherche/recherche.php) to impute my low resolution typings into high resolution ones but I have this error when I upload my file:

[image]

Has anyone ever used this tool? I wanted to use it because it is said to be better than HaploStats (couldn't find a reliable source though) but I couldn't make it work so I cannot even compare them.

Comment: This isn't really the kind of question we welcome here, though I can understand your desire for an answer and the logic to posting it on Biology.SE. I'm a technophobe, so when I'm frustrated by a product (if I paid for it), I call their customer or tech support. If it's a popular product, it may have its own forum for problem solving. No disrespect intended, just trying to help (with the full realization that help isn't likely to come from a technophobe!)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I was hoping someone might have been using it on a regular basis.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about a problem in biology.

Comment: Not a problem at all; as I mentioned, it was a logical place to post. Please don't take the closure personally; it's a site issue. I forgot to say welcome. Welcome! I hope we can help you in some other way(s). :)

Comment: A 504 error is a server error caused by lack of response of an upstream server. The website owners are the only people who can fix it. You might be able to contact a webmaster for the page indicated (try going to the homepage and see if there is a webmaster contact).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used it in the past and you typically have to wait several hours between the moment where you upload the file and the moment you can download the result. The website will not be accessible in the meantime.

About a source proving it's better, there is a [github repository](https://github.com/JasonMendoza2008/HLATypingImputationBenchmarks) I found a few weeks ago that benchmarks different imputation tools and does find better results for HLA Upgrade compared to HaploStats as you mentioned. However, it seems HaploSFHI yields better results overall. It's only one random github repository though, I wouldn't trust it blindly.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, my file went through!! Thank you

Comment: You can also contact them at easy-hla@univ-nantes.fr, it's hard to find but it''s written at the bottom of the page ;)

Comment: Huzzah! An answer!